# Not able to open popup on window exit

Tags: jquery

i want to open a jquery popup `loadSound();` when someone closes browser.But its not opening the popup.

Code working:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    alert("hello");
}
```

Code not working:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    loadSound();
}
```

don't know why it works with `alert("hello");` but not with `loadSound();`

Whole code:

```
function lightbox(){
    //to adjust popup width adjust here
    $.colorbox({inline:true, href:"#inline_content",onClosed: pauseSound, overlayClose: false});
}

function pauseSound() {
    document.getElementById("notification_sound").pause();
}       
///////////////////pop strts here
function loadSound() {
    lightbox();
    document.getElementById("notification_sound").play();
}  
///////////////popup ends here

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    loadSound();
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  I don't think your users will actually want this.  `onbeforeunload` is *very* picky about what can happen.  It's meant *ONLY* for clean up purposes, and to ask if the user wants to leave.  That's it.  Browsers can choose to block code from running inside the `onbeforeunload` method, or they can choose to not even trigger it.

Comment: but  i need to open popup on page exit....

Comment: If you return a string from `onbeforeunload`, the browser will give you a "are you sure you want to leave?" popup (and may or may not display your string on it).  That's all you can do.  You cannot trigger your own popup.

Comment: so there's not any way to do this???

Comment: What *exactly* do you want to do?

Comment: when someone leaves the page i want to open it..

Comment: The problem is that `onbeforeunload` will not wait for your popup to open or your sound to play.  So this code might work, but the page will exit before it does.  So, no, you can't do this.

Comment: can't we do this with `onunload();` ?

Comment: No.  `onunload` will also not wait.  The problem is: you code is running fine, but the page is leaving before the popup opens.  There is no way to make the page wait for that to happen.  When you leave the page, that's what the browser is going to do.

Comment: Why do you want a popup to open anyway?  If the user is leaving the page, why do you want to show him a popup?  Is it to ask if he wants to leave or not?  If so, if you return a string from `onbeforeunload`, the *browser* will ask him if he wants to leave.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "hello do you wan to get out?";
}
```